# You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I recently clone a project of **react-native-expo** after fixing some issue when I'm trying to create a build it give me an error which is:

```
You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation.

Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[28acedc0-1ad3-4d4c-95be-048c5931487c] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[79c3a180-b551-4a89-a213-efb039f527c0], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1)

Request ID: e842ee8d-bc17-4c68-910d-63c07f33d464
```

I don't know why I'm getting this issue I perform these steps

1. `eas login`
2. `eas build --platform ios`

Comment: Did you try prefix your commands with npx ```npx eas build --platform ios ```

Comment: yes I did but it would not work.

Comment: Delete the ```projectId``` in your app.json, the project id in the app.json don’t belong to your account.

Comment: Then how can i generate that again?

Comment: It should automatically generate a new one.